# Can't get anonymous access to website

Tags: iis, iis-6, webserver, anonymous-access

I have already asked this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/88171/configuring-website-for-anonymous-access/88182#88182) on ServerFault however I got very minimal replies....one to be exact.

I need this issue resolved ASAP hence why I am asking on here aswell. I have a server running Windows Server 2003 IIS6.0. I am developing a website to which I want to grant anonymous access to. I have created a new Website in the IIS Manager I have ensured the "Enable Anonymous access" option is enabled and it has been set to IUSR_*MachineName*.

I have sync'd the passwords between IIS metabase, AD and MTA and made sure IUSR_*MachineName* has been given the relevent permissions. I just can't seem to get this to work. Everytime I try to access the webpage I get prompted to login. I set the anonymous login account to be my own (admin) account and tried that and it worked ok so I know it must be a permissions issue with the IUSR account.

Please help me I am fairly new to IIS/Server management and I am tearing my hair out!!

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the IIS logs and the event log? Those might contain useful hints.

Comment: Make sure that the account is not disabled.

Comment: Firstly why close this question I have said I have already asked this on ServerFault and not gotten any responses. @tijmendvk I have checked the event long nothing really noticable in there, where can I see the IIS logs?

Comment: What do you mean by "made sure IUSR_MachineName has been given the relevent permissions"? IUSR_machinename has nothing to do with AD, it's a local machine account.  If this is a .net app, did you perhaps set different access permissions in web.config?

Comment: @Kevin, the account is defintely enabled.

Comment: @Lyman I mean I have given IUSR_machinename permissions to read the directory. At the minute it is a basic HTML page with an image

Comment: Is a static site, an ASP.NET site, or something else?  If you're using ASP.NET you should double check your web.config file to be sure you're not setting authentication differently than you have in IIS.

Comment: @Jason at the moment it is a basic static site

Comment: @everyone, thanks guys I realised what I was going wrong. On the wizard when creating a new website I was checking the "enable running scripts" DOH!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What technology are you using to produce the website?

If it's .net, have you configured the web.config to perhaps require some sort of authentication?

Typically if you want anonymous access, you use IIS as default, check the enable anonymous access, and you're done.
You shouldn't need to change anything else.

Try creating a new website in iis, with a dummy html page and see if you can configure that to work without any authentication.

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong by pretty much doing what you said. I was ticking the "run scripts (ASP)" in the wizard when creating a new website. Thanks